# How to fail liquibase changeset with unexpected condition?

Tags: mysql, liquibase, changeset

I have changesets like below,

```
<changeSet id="project1">
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" path="abc.sql"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="project2" author="akshay">
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" path="xyz.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

When I execute liquibase, it executes both the changesets. The issue is that it doesn't fail if any of the query inside the sql files fail. Instead it just continues and executes all the changesets.

I checked about preconditions, but with precondition, we will be able to avoid only the conditions what we know already like disk space should be good enough, table already exist.

Is there a way to fail the liquibase when any of the sql query inside any of the changeset fails?

Comment: What kind of error is being thrown by MySql?

Comment: If Liquibase doesn't report any failure, how do you know that a query failed?
Whenever an SQL error occurs, Liquibase will stop and report a failure.
So, if Liquibase didn't report anything, I assume the queries didn't fail, but they did nothing or at least not what you expected.
So, what is in the SQL? What result did you expect? And what was the result?